# after_find or after_initialize does not work with updating form fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

The after_find or after_initialize does not seem to update odometer on my vehicle/edit.html.erb view.

View:

```
= form_for(@vehicle) do |f|
  = f.number_field :odometer
```

Model:

```
after_find :standardise_numbers
...
def standardise_numbers
    metric ? self.odometer.miles.to.kilometers : self.odometer
end
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Is this after submission of the form?  Or on rendering the `/edit` view?

Comment: on rendering /edit view. I need to convert odometer from miles to kilometers on the render of the /edit view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`= f.number_field :odometer` will simply return whatever the value is for `@vehicle.odometer`.  You'll want to have a helper function that calls `standarise_numbers` on `@vehicle` within the form.

You could do it without a helper as well:

```
= form_for(@vehicle) do |f|
  = f.number_field :odometer, :value => @vehicle.odometer
```

I just prefer to use helpers rather than make model method calls in a view.

Another option would be to override the `odometer` accessor on `Vehicle`:

```
class Vehicle << ActiveRecord::Base

  def odometer
    metric ? self.read_attribute(:odometer).miles.to.kilometers : self.read_attribute(:odometer)
  end

end
```

Reference:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/number_field_tag

Comment: I tried this and got: `undefined method '1609.344' for #<Vehicle:0x007f5335184180>`

Comment: ok, cool. I now get: `undefined method 'merge' for 1609.344:Float` getting close!

Comment: Try explicitly giving the `:value` key as above.  `:value => @vehicle.standardise_numbers`

Comment: That shouldn't matter though...  What does `@vehicle.standardise_numbers` give you for that `@vehicle` in console?

Comment: Perfect! Very nice! :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40881/discussion-between-bruno-and-cdub)